# Stacked/Dodged barplot using base R with x-axis is numerical data

Tags: r, grouping, bar-chart, stacked

I have looked at all barplot questions in the sites but still couldn't figure out what to do with my dataset. I don't know if it's a duplicate but any help would be so much appreciated

My dataset

```
Region   Scenario     HC      NPV1       NPV2
C          1           0.1     10          5
C          2           0.2      8          4
C          3           0.3      7          3 
C          4           0.4      6          2
N          1           0.1     10          5
N          2           0.2      8          4
N          3           0.3      7          3 
N          4           0.4      6          2
W          1           0.1     10          5
W          2           0.2      8          4
W          3           0.3      7          3 
W          4           0.4      6          2
```

I want to create a barplot where HC, Scenario is at x-axis, NPV1 and NPV2 is the height and be distinguished by different patterns. A region should be a common name in the middle of each 4 scenarios.

Thanks a lot.

Expected output is something like this.

[image]

Comment: Are you only looking for base R solutions or are you also interested in `ggplot` approaches?

Comment: On further reflection, I am actually not clear on *how* you'd like to visualise your data. Can you provide a mock-up of your expected output plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my above comments, I'm quite unclear about *how* you'd like to visualise your data. What exactly would you like to show on the x axis?

As a start, perhaps you are after something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(key, val, -Region, -Scenario, -HC) %>%
    unite(x, Region, Scenario, HC) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, val, fill = key)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

Here categories on the x-axis are of the form `<Region>_<Scenario>_<HC>`.

---

### Update

To achieve a plot similar to the one you're showing you can do the following

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(key, val, -Region, -Scenario, -HC) %>%
    ggplot(aes(HC, val, fill = key)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge2") +
    facet_wrap(~Region, nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Explanation: `strip.position = "bottom"` ensures that strip labels are at the bottom, and `strip.placement = "outside"` ensures that strip labels are below the axis labels (to be precise, between the axis labels and axis title).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
"Region Scenario HC NPV1 NPV2
C 1 0.1 10 5
C 2 0.2 8 4
C 3 0.3 7 3
C 4 0.4 6 2
N 1 0.1 10 5
N 2 0.2 8 4
N 3 0.3 7 3
N 4 0.4 6 2
W 1 0.1 10 5
W 2 0.2 8 4
W 3 0.3 7 3
W 4 0.4 6 2
", header = T)
```

Comment: Hi Maurit, I'm looking for base R option if possible. I'm trying to avoid using ggplot due to a few problem.

Comment: In the x axis I would like to visualize something like: 
In the first row with tick is the value of HC
Below the value of HC is Scenario 1, 2, 3 accordingly
and Final row is the region name which is one per 4 scenario, in the middle of 4 scenario. Does it make sense?

Comment: @Lara Can you edit your post to show a mock-up figure? I think this might be quite tricky to do, especially the multiple rows of x labels will be difficult to realise in base R (and `ggplot` for that matter).

Comment: Hi Maurits, otherwise I would remove the row of scenario. Only need the value of HC in x-axis and the region possibly can be used by mtext?

Comment: I guess it can also be 3 graphs, each graph represents one region and name of the region in each graph but all three graphs should be in one plot.

Comment: @Lara The easiest way would be via facets in `ggplot`, which you don't want to use. But can you *please* add a mock-up of your expected output plot? This would certainly help a lot with understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi I've just added a mock-up of my expected output plot using excel. Data is a bit different tho.

Comment: Thanks @Lara, now we're getting somewhere. By the way, the plot you're after is not a *stacked* barplot, but a plot where bars are *dodged*. In any case, I still think this is easiest done in `ggplot`, and I would urge you to reconsider. I will update my post with an example...

Comment: Yes, I realize maybe dodged bars are clearer so I change to that. Okay if baseR cannot be used then I would have to use ggplot. Thanks a lot

Comment: Perfect! That's what I need. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're very welcome @Lara; glad we got there in the end.